# Joining two tables with many to many relationship fields

Tags: javascript, mysql, google-apps-script

I'm working on google data studio and trying to fetch the data from a third-party system. In that case, there is a problem in the third-party system, because it doesn't allow for SQL join. Therefore, I got the data by using 2 URLs separately and joined the two tables(customer_order table & Customer_Order_Demand table). But the problem is there is a field(Order_NO) that has many to many relationships in one table. According to my code, I'm getting only first value in Order_No column after joining the two tables. I want to display the number of orders for each Item by corresponding date.

```
  Customer Order Demand Table                                        
+-----------------------------+ 
| id  | item     |    Date    |         
|-----|----------|------------| 
|  1  |  BLU     | 7/10/2020  |  
|  2  |  PM      | 7/20/2020  |   
|  3  |  BLU     | 7/23/2020  |          
+-----------------------------+ 


    Customer Order Table                                        
+---------------------------------------------------------+
| id  |  COD_id         |  Order_NO      |   Date         |
|-----|----------------------------------|----------------|
|  1  |      1          |  #100          |    7/10/2020   |
|  2  |      1          |  #130          |    7/10/2020   |
|  3  |      2          |  #200          |    7/20/2020   |
|  4  |      3          |  #500          |    7/23/2020   | 
+---------------------------------------------------------+

                   Expected  Table                                        
+-----------------------------------------------+
|     |  Item    |    Date    |  Order_NO       |
|-----|----------|------------|-----------------|
|  1  |  BLU     | 7/10/2020  |  #100 /#130     |
|  2  |  PM      | 7/20/2020  |  #200           |
|  3  |  BLU     | 7/23/2020  |  #500           |        
+-----------------------------------------------+
```

```
 var url=[
    'http://test.smartapps.lk/rest/api/selectQuery?sessionId=' + SessionId + '&maxRows=10&query=select id, Item, Date from Customer_Order_demand &output=json'
  ].join('');
  
  var url2=[
    'http://test.smartapps.lk/rest/api/selectQuery?sessionId=' + SessionId + '&maxRows=10&query=select id,Order_NO from Customer_Order &output=json'
  ].join(''); 
  
  
  var responseID2 = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  var responseID3 = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url2);
   
  var table1 = JSON.parse(responseID2.getContentText());     
  var table2 = JSON.parse(responseID3.getContentText());
   
  var finalArray = [];
  
  for(var i in table1){
      for(var j in table2){

        //Joining two tables 
        if(table1[i][0]==table2[j][0]){

            // converting to json object
             var newObj = {      
             "Item": table1[i][1],
             "Date":table1[i][2],
             "Order_NO": table2[j][1] 
             };
          
         finalArray.push(newObj);
        }
      }
   
  }
  
   return finalArray;
```

Comment: Store data using the correct data type for that data. Then see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query), and get back to us.

Answer (score 1):

- [Reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) the second table to a [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) :

  ```
  const table2map = table2.reduce(
    (mp,[codId,ordNo]) => 
        mp.set(codId,
         mp.has(codId)
          ? [...mp.get(codId),ordNo]
          : [ordNo]
        ), new Map
  )
  ```
- [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) table1 to a array of objects:

  ```
  const finalArr = table1.map(
    ([id,Item,Date]) =>
        ({Item,Date,
        "Order_No": table2map.get(id).join()})
  )
  ```